# Getting ... yelp_soup is not defined when writting scraper script

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, yelp

I'm getting the error:

> yelp_soup is not defined when writting scraper script

I don't know why, this is code copied from the udemy course, but it works for them. Why is that?

this is link to the github from where I copied it as a last resort but not working:

https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/30-Days-of-Python/blob/master/Day%2021%20-%2023/scrape/code/scape.py

Any suggestions? I tried few ideas but nothing changed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified a little to serve the purpose. Run this and let me know if you encounter further issues:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Restaurants&find_loc='
loc = 'Newport+Beach,+CA'
page = 10

url = base_url + loc + "&start=" + str(page)
yelp_soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

for biz in yelp_soup.find_all(class_='biz-listing-large'):
    title = biz.find_all(class_='biz-name')[0].text
    address = biz.select('address,.biz-parent-container')[0].text
    phone = biz.find_all(class_='biz-phone')[0].text
    print(title.strip(),address.strip(),phone.strip())
```

Comment: Why am i still getting. name yelp_soup is not defined?  Still getting errors :/

Comment: Are you sure you have installed `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` libraries?

Comment: I did now. I deleted whole folder, redone everything, reinstalled libraries again, and now it works perfectly. Dont know why though

Comment: If it works, then make sure to accept it as an answer by ticking the checkmark adjacent to my answer. Thanks.